# How to connect fonts to wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am facing a problem with connecting fonts in WordPress.

In style css i have this segment of code, which must get the fonts from the file with fonts.

```
/** reset, vars, fonts **/

/** fonts **/

/** color **/

@font-face {
  font-family: "ProximaNova-Black";
  font-display: swap;
  src: url("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/fonts/ProximaNova-Black.woff") format("woff"), url("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/fonts/ProximaNova-Black.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
```

The files of the site look like this.
[image: Site's files]
[image: Fonts file opend]

this is the fonts file opened.

A code sample of how i connect my fonts.

```
  .header__title h1 {
  font-family: ProximaNova-Black;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  color: #83be80;
}
```

Where is mine mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_template_directory_uri()` is a PHP function and can only be executed within a PHP tag. You can't use it on the style.css file since it's being executed as CSS, not PHP.

Just use a relative path like this assuming the CSS file is on top of your theme directory.

In `style.css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "ProximaNova-Black";
  font-display: swap;
  src: url("fonts/ProximaNova-Black.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/ProximaNova-Black.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

The folder structure should be like this.

```
my-theme/
├─ fonts/
│  ├─ ProximaNova-Black.woff
│  ├─ ProximaNova-Black.woff2
├─ inc/
├─ js/
├─ languages/
├─ index.php
├─ [...any other files...]
├─ style.css
```

Comment: Great answer mate!